# Microsoft Interop Find and Replace with Formatting

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, office-interop, office-automation

I am making a windows form app that will take in user input and upon submission it will open a word template and find and replace date from the windows form to the word document. I would like the replaced text to be underlined. I am using a function I found from another user but I am not sure how to set up the formatting. Here is the function I am using:

```
private void FindAndReplace(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp, object toFindText, object replaceWithText)
{
    object matchCase = true;
    object matchwholeWord = true;
    object matchwildCards = false;
    object matchSoundLike = false;
    object nmatchAllforms = false;
    object forward = true;
    object format = false;
    object matchKashida = false;
    object matchDiactitics = false;
    object matchAlefHamza = false;
    object matchControl = false;
    object read_only = false;
    object visible = true;
    object replace = -2;
    object wrap = 1;
    wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(ref toFindText, ref matchCase,
                                    ref matchwholeWord, ref matchwildCards, ref matchSoundLike,
                                    ref nmatchAllforms, ref forward,
                                    ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText,
                                    ref replace, ref matchKashida,
                                    ref matchDiactitics, ref matchAlefHamza,
                                    ref matchControl);
}
```

I can see there is a object format = false, but when I check the documentation I do not see how I can set the formatting options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. I just added a line of code in the function I used above, below the line

```
wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(ref toFindText, ref matchCase,
                               ref matchwholeWord, ref matchwildCards, ref matchSoundLike,
                               ref nmatchAllforms, ref forward,
                               ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText,
                               ref replace, ref matchKashida,
                               ref matchDiactitics, ref matchAlefHamza,
                               ref matchControl);
```

I added

```
wordApp.Selection.Font.Underline = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineSingle;
```